# Why I cannot break the value assignment into two different statements?

Tags: c, pointers, null, initialization, variable-assignment

```
   #inlude <stdio.h>
   typedef struct node
   {
     int data, height, count;
     struct node *left, *right, *father;
   }node;
   node *root = NULL;
   void main(){
   //some code here
   }
```

Above code gives no error, but

```
  #inlude <stdio.h>
   typedef struct node
   {
     int data, height, count;
     struct node *left, *right, *father;
   }node;
   node *root;
   root = NULL;
   void main(){
   //some code here
   }
```

this produces the following error:

```
sample.c:11:1: error: conflicting types for 'root' 
sample.c: 10:7 note: previous declaration of 'root' was here 
node *root; 
      ^
```

The above error is not reproduced when the statement

```
root = NULL;
```

is declared within `main function`

What could be the reason?

Comment: You can't just assign a variable outside of a function, when it is not a part of the initialization.

Comment: Note that all global variables are zero-initialized, there's no point in reinitializing them to zero like you do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case,

```
 node *root = NULL;
```

is an **[initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming))** while declaration. That is explicitly allowed in global scope.

On the other hand,

```
node *root;
root = NULL;
```

is a declaration **and** an **[assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))**, the later being a statement to be executed, it has to be in some function scope. It cannot reside in global scope.

Thus, in your case, `root` being a global variable, is perfectly accessible from `main()` and the assignment statement is also legal there. No complains.